# Is $f(x)=\Gamma(x)^{\Gamma(x)},\quad x>0$ a convex function.

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, gamma-function

Is $$f(x)=\Gamma(x)^{\Gamma(x)},\quad x>0$$ a convex function.

In my attempt to solve this problem I tried to use the fact that Gamma is a convex function when x>0, I could not complete the proof.

> Question is given by Jalil Hajimir.

Comment: You could provide some details what went wrong. Also it could be false, have you tried disproving it?

Comment: Study the variations of $\Gamma(x)^{\Gamma(x)} = e^{\Gamma(x)ln(\Gamma(x))}$ over $]0, +\infty[$, derive it twice, show $\frac{d^2(\Gamma(x)^{\Gamma(x)})}{dx^2} > 0$

Comment: It suffices to show that $\Gamma(x) \ln(\Gamma(x))$ is convex since $e^x$ is convex and monotonically increasing.